# My program to create randomly generated numbers into an array keeps crashing

Tags: c++, arrays, class, random, crash

So recently I've made a piece of code that randomly generates an array (or bundle) but it crashes when I try to run and I have no idea why. I'm fairly new to coding and I'm unsure where the logical error is.

So the program basically is meant to make a multi dimensional array that randomly generates "orders" for PC's. I attempted to make the bundle that creates from 150-250 orders but if that isn't possible (or too complicated) I can make it just 250. The order is  (orderId (just goes from 1 to however many orders there are), PCId (a random number 0-15), orderQuantity(random number from 1-20), dueDate (random number from 0-4), profit (not yet configured, just ignore for now)). And in the array it is this order

```
{orderId, PCId, orderQuantity, dueDate, profit}
```

I would like to understand why it doesn't show any errors in the IDE but crashes when running!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class BundleGenerator
{
public:
    BundleGenerator();
    void generateBundle();

protected:
    int numberOfOrders;
    int bundleArray[][5];
    int orderId;
    int PCId;
    int quantity;
    int dueDay;
    int profit;
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    BundleGenerator bg;
    bg.generateBundle();
    return 0;
}

BundleGenerator::BundleGenerator()
{
    int randNum;
    randNum = rand()%(250-150 + 1) + 150;
    numberOfOrders = randNum;
}
void BundleGenerator::generateBundle()
{
    orderId = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfOrders; i++)
    {
        bundleArray[i][0] = orderId;
        orderId++;

        int PCIdRnd = rand()%15;
        PCId = PCIdRnd;
        bundleArray[i][1] = PCId;

        int quantityRnd = rand()%19;
        quantity = quantityRnd;
        bundleArray[i][2] = quantity;

        int dueDayRnd = rand()%4;
        dueDay = dueDayRnd;
        bundleArray[i][3] = dueDay;

        bundleArray[i][4] = 0;
    }
}
```

Any advice on the program would be awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: I think the easiest (and most educational) thing for you to do would be to throw in a few breakpoints and step though the code using Visual Studio.

Comment: You are never initializing bundleArray.  You have to use malloc or calloc to allocate memory for them to point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be on "int bundleArray[][5];", it seems that, you does not provide any memory for the array.

Comment: Notice that, C++ just not works like Java, instead it works the same as C in memory management. You will have to manage the memory by yourself.